# Blender for iOS without using sidecar or duet?

Tags: installation

I'd like to use blender on my iPad. Is there any direct download link for iOS?

Comment: why don't you want to use sidecar?

Answer (score 1):

Blender is written in C++, mostly.  Apple requires iOS apps to be written in either Objective-C or Swift and doesn't provide runtime support for C++, so there is no way to run Blender without alternative support.  As far as I know, there is no useable C++ runtime for iOS that would support Blender.

Answer (score -1):

No.

If it were Android, it might be another matter, but no way on iOS.